# How do I edit a specific tag of an XML datafile using sed?

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I have the XML code as follows

```
<root>
    <list>
        <pair name="id" Value="randomvalue" />
    </list>
    <list>
        <pair name="place" Value="US" />
    </list>
</root>
```

I need to change the Value(could be any value which we dont know) of the pair tag(whose name attribute is "id") to say "othervalue".

I have tried using:
`sed -i 's|<pair name="id" Value="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" />$|<pair name="id" Value="othervalue" />|g' file.xml`

But it doesn't work

Comment: One problem you're running into, btw, is that in POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax, which is what `sed` uses by default, `+` is not a special token.

Comment: _"How do I edit [...] XML using sed?"_ You don't! You should use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed`, [as is almost always the case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9952196) when it comes to XML, is the wrong thing to use here. Use a tool that understands the format natively, like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php). One of its many modes allows you to assign a new value to an attribute or element that matches an XPath expression (Which is a much better and more precise way to match part of an XML document than trying to use regular expressions):

```sh
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '/root/list/pair[@name="id"]/@Value' -v othervalue file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <list>
    <pair name="id" Value="othervalue"/>
  </list>
  <list>
    <pair name="place" Value="US"/>
  </list>
</root>
```

In `xmlstarlet ed`, `-u xpath` means "Update the bit that matches the given XPath expression" and `-v blah` means "With this value".

Add the `--inplace` option to modify your XML file in-place once you've verified it does the right thing:

```sh
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/root/list/pair[@name="id"]/@Value' -v othervalue file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't there any other command other than xmlstarlet to solve this?

Comment: Probably, but xmlstarlet's a very popular choice for working with XML from a script or command line.